# Azure service bus topic - subscription message is received. How to find the consumer/client

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I have a scenario where an Azure SB subscription message is being received by an unknown consumer/client. We landed in this scenario as we have multiple function apps/logic apps running.

I would like to pause all the consumers/client for that subscription for some time but cannot find any way out.

Is there any audit log that can give me information about which "client" is connected to which "topic/queue".

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any audit log that can give me information about which "client" is connected to which "topic/queue".

Broker side logging feature is not available at this point. You won't be able to determine the client that is trying to access the specified subscription.

> I have a scenario where an Azure SB subscription message is being received by an unknown consumer/client.

With Azure Service Bus consumer/client **has** to be known for security reasons. You're either giving out a connection string or a SAS token. Trying to reset those tokens or Shared Access keys would be another avenue, but it would mean affecting anyone else using those.